# JMicron Box issue with Raspberry PI 400

Tags: boot, boot-issues

I've changed my SanDisk Extreme Portable SSD V2( was broken ) , with new one SSD + box

My new SSD is Lexar NS100 LNS100256AMZN (Amazon Edition) and box is [TooQ TQE-2524B](https://www.tooq.com/product.php?id=1568&lang=2).

Operating System is Raspberry pi OS 64 Bit 2023-02-21

I copy with Raspberry Pi Imager v1.7.3 the OS, but when connect to Rapsbbery PI 400 boot start few minutes monitor remain black.

How to solve it ? Windows 10 detect Box as Jmicron Generic SCSI Disk Device

**Update**

If connect in usb 2.0 port SSD work

lsusb detect box as JMS578